# Adding an array to a document in firebase from flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a new collection with two values in it's document, one is a string and the other is an array.
it worked when I added the string without the array, so my problem is with the array.
this is the function I wrote to set the new collection

```
void addCategory({required String addedCategory, required List tags}) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Category").doc(addedCategory).set({
    'name': addedCategory,
    'Tags': [tags]
  }).then((value) {
    emit(CategoryAdded());
  });
}
```

and this the calling

```
UserCubit.get(context).addCategory(
  addedCategory: 'Resturants', tags: ['Italian', 'Romanian']
);
```

If anyone can help I'll be thankful.

Comment: Since your `tags` is a `List`, shouldn't it be `'Tags': tags`?

Comment: As Frank has already pointed it out, you're putting a list in a list, that too improperly, it should be just `'Tags: tags`. Also, point to note here is Firebase doesn't support nested Lists either, so even if this was intentional, it would've worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags is already a list and it should not be sent as `list<list>`

```
void addCategory({required String addedCategory, required List tags}) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Category").doc(addedCategory).set({
    'name': addedCategory,
    'Tags': [tags], // remove this line
    'Tags': tags,   // add this line
  }).then((value) {
    emit(CategoryAdded());
  });
}
```